# How to grab Category + children in my ForEach Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, categories

[**Modal Bootstrap filter box with categories + children**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGi1n.png)

Hello all, I'm trying to create a Foreach in wordpress for the bootstrap modal to grab the category + children. I'm working with the Search and Filter plugin Pro so I need the url to echo out the category name but not its url at the end of the url which i'm struggling to figure out how to add it at the end, example below. Any help would be greatly appreciated Thank you all:

```
 <?php
             $categories =   wp_list_categories( array(
             'orderby'            => 'id',
             'use_desc_for_title' => false,
             'child_of'           => 216
            ) );
            foreach($category as $categories) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-3"><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/our-companies/?_sft_category=**category name!** "></a></div>';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to display all categories ? or child of a sepecified category ?

Comment: Just the children of the specified category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your query and loop.  Try this:

```
<?php

    $categories = get_terms( array(

      'taxonomy' => 'category', // set the taxonomy
      'orderby' => 'ID', // orderby cat ID
      'parent' => 216 // set parent ID to get child cats

       )
     );


    foreach($categories as $cat) {

    $cat_slug = $cat->slug; // get category slug
    $site_url = get_site_url(); // get site url
    $cat_url = $site_url . '/our-companies?_sft_category=' . $cat_slug; // put url together

    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">

      <!-- echo your url in to your href -->

      <a href="<?php echo $cat_url; ?>">Link text</a>

    </div>    

    <?php }
```

Comment: Updated the query, needed to add array() for the arguments, forgot that initially.

Comment: This worked with a few minor adjustments but thank you so much!

Comment: Great.  If this solved your issue be sure to mark it this answer solved to help others that may have similar questions.  Glad it helped you accomplish your need.

Comment: I actually have a quick question. in the URL, I just realized I would need to add the category slug instead of the name. I realized this because it's been adding %20 in between the category names instead of the slugs with the dashes - Any idea how to? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer to account for using slug instead of name